# How come this doesn't stop the form from submitting/ reloading the page?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a little search script, but can't seem to stop the page from re-loading when you hit submit. There is probably something wrong with my code:

```
function searchThat(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    e.preventDefault();

    if (searchFor.indexOf(searchIn) != -1) {
        console.log('we found it');
    }
}
```

Thanks a bunch!

I am calling it with

```
    if (searchFor && searchIn && searchSubmit) {
    addEvent(searchSubmit, 'submit', searchThat)
    }
```

and:

```
function addEvent(elem, evtType, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(evtType, func, false);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + evtType, func);
    } else {
        elem["on" + evtType] = func;
    }
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <p>Search for:</p>
        <p class="mrm">
            <input type="text" id="searchFor" name="searchFor">
        </p>
        <p>In:</p>
        <textarea class="mrm" type="text" id="searchIn" name="searchIn"></textarea>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="clicker nmb" id="searchSubmit" name="searchSubmit">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Its something about how you "submit". Post code.

Comment: I assume `searchSubmit` is `<form>`?

Comment: We need to see the HTML form, specifically the code you're using to call the javascript.

Comment: Form Submit causes postback. it's a normal behavior. Do you have to Submit ? Can you just execute your method on a click of a button/link ?

Comment: `searchSubmit` is the Id of the `<input type="submit">`

Comment: Do you have to submit or can addEvent be rewritten for 'click' ?

Comment: It can, but the form submit reloads the page even if there is no JS at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Input type="submit"/>` will always trigger postback and reload the page.
If it works with whatever you're trying to implement change your input to `<Input type="button"/>`

And

```
addEvent(searchSubmit, 'click', searchThat)
{}
```

There could be more logic that your code is missing but from what you've posted you can make your life even easier by instead of doing all this complicated JScripting you can just do:
`<Input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="searchThat()"/>`